# How to convert a Gaussian matrix into a probability matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, probability, gaussian

I have a 150 * 150 matrix derived from another 150 * 150 matrix( which follows a Gaussian function with 1 ant the center of the matrix). So the largest value of the derived matrix is at the center. I want to convert this derived matrix into a matrix where:
1) each position of the matrix denotes the probability of that position being the centroid of some object based on the value of that position.
2) Sum of all resulting values of the converted matrix = 1
Can somebody suggest how to proceed with this?

Comment: Your first requirement is unclear, please give a small (5x5?) example matrix we can use, and show exactly what you want at the end.

Comment: If you want `sum(m) = 1` then you should `m = M/sum(M)`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Suppose we have a 5*5 matrix A where each element is calculated as:  A_(i,j)=np.exp(-((i-x0)**2+(j-y0)**2) / 2 * (0.1**2)). This matrix will follow gaussian function with 1 at the center(x0,y0). I took a fft of this,multiplied with another matrix, then took ifft of the product. Now, I want to convert the values of the product into probability as mentioned above.

Comment: Tthe elements of the matrix should add upto 1 since it is supposed to be  probability matrix. I need to create such a matrix.